# I am new to web designing so need help at installsation of datatable table tools from datatable.net

Tags: jquery, excel, datatable

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable();
    });
    </script>
<body>
    <table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
    <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

this is what i use to handle data table  but i am unble to use its pdf xml exporter plugin name table tools
http://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/

Answer (score 0):

You first need of scripts.

- [jquery.js](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.js)
- [dataTables.js](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js)
- [tableTools.js](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js)
- [dataTables.css](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css)
- [tableTools.css](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/css/dataTables.tableTools.css)
- [Swf Path](https://github.com/DataTables/TableTools/tree/master/swf)

Then you need to set your DataTable. Like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "tableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            "aButtons": [
                "copy",
                "print",
                {
                    "sExtends":    "collection",
                    "sButtonText": "Save",
                    "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf" ]
                }
            ]
        }
    } );
} );
```

Try yourself, and come back here if you have any questions.

In this link: [Examples](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/extensions/TableTools/examples/index.html), there are several examples.

Hope this helps.